# @Value In Spring MVC is not getting populated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to populate an attribute using the @Value annotation in Spring MVC, and it is not getting populated.

I am trying to access the attribute using Struts2 JSP  property. my use case looks like that:

```
public class TransferCreditsAction extends StudentAwareAction {

   protected Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

   @Value( "${transfer.credit.url}" )
   private String transferCreditUrl;

   public void setStates( List<TranslatedValue> states ) {
      this.states = states;
   }

   @Value( "${transfer.credit.url}" )
   public String getTransferCreditUrl() {
      return transferCreditUrl;
   }
}
```

My property file looks like:

```
transfer.credit.url
```

I am accessing this attribute using JSP  which looks like:

```
<s:property value='transferCreditUrl'/>"
```

I know for a fact that my JSP can access this field, because I tested it when I have this field set for a default value.

However, this field is not getting populated from my property file. I am using Spring 4.1.6

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: is TransferCreditsAction is bean? I dont see any component annotation on it?

Comment: Yes its a Spring bean already.
I have multiple contexts, and for this particular context I have this bean declared in it. I think my issue is because I have multiple contexts and I have some conflicts in the definition of **PropertyPlaceholderVariableLocationConfigurer**. I will update my question so it looks more clear.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by adding 
<context:annotation-config/>
to my applicationContext xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was happening because I was missing `<context:annotation-config/>` in my applicationContext. Once I added it, it start working with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can only inject values in its own managed spring beans. That means your `TransferCreditsAction` should be a spring bean.

There are various ways to declare your `TransferCreditsAction` class as a spring bean, already answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added whats on top of `TransferCreditsAction` class. 
Values will be injected in a Bean Env.

There are many ways of Doing it

Assuming my property file contains

```
username=Ashish
app.name=Hello
```

1.

```
@Service
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:sample.properties" })
public class PaloAltoSbiClientImpl implements PaloAltoSbiClient {

    public static String username;

    @Value("${username}")
    public void setUrl(String data) {
        username = data;
    }

...
```

2.

```
@Service
public class PaloAltoSbiClientImpl implements PaloAltoSbiClient {

    @Value("${username}")
    public static String username;


...
```

3.

```
@Component
public class TokenHelper {

    @Value("${app.name}")
    private String APP_NAME;
```

Comment: I have not added the code that I am extending since it was really tested and irrelevant to this use case. however this issue was related to having multiple application context files, and the I have not activate the annotation to be detected in my main context file. 
`<context:annotation-config/>` was enough to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the properties file reference on top of the class in which you are trying to get.

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:sample.properties" })
```

Comment: It was not really this issue.